# Moving Curl client ssl to Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, ssl, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle v3.9.2 with both php 5.3 and php 5.5.

I have the following working curl code that uses an ssl client certificate:

```
$url = "https://example.com/";
$cert_file = '/path/to/certificate.pem';

$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_URL => $url ,
  CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert_file ,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$output) {
  echo "Curl Error : " . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  echo htmlentities($output);
}
```

I have tried to move it to Guzzle:

```
require '/var/www/vendor/autoload.php';
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->get($url, array('cert' => $cert_file));
$response = $client->send($request);
echo $response . PHP_EOL;
print 'HI' . PHP_EOL;
```

When I run it using curl I get a 200 response. When I use Guzzle I get a 403.

Comment: `cert` option only work with client certificate. If you are using private certificate then curl will gave you unable to set private key file error. Please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try like this:

```
 $client = new Client();
 $response = $client->get($url, array(), array('cert' => $cert_file));
```

and for check add this line:

```
 $this->assertEquals($cert_file, $request->getCurlOptions()->get(CURLOPT_SSLCERT));
```

or use this:

```
 $client = new Client();
 $request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url);
 $request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert_file);
 $response = $client->send($request);
```

if you use self singed certificate set this options :

```
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

set this line before send request :

```
$request = $client->get( .... )
.
.
.
$request->setResponse(new Response(200), true);
$request->send();
```

check your url and enter it compelete like this :

```
$url = 'https://example.com/index.php';
```

and you can add default options like your curl code :

```
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
$request->getCurlOptions()->set(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
```

Comment: Well, good news and bad. The assertEquals stuff does indeed show the exact same value. But...somehow it still doesn't work. Any more ideas on how to debug?

Comment: before send request use var_dump($request->getCurlOptions()); and see created curloptions

Comment: This got me to the answer and I believe is generally the most accurate answer, so I accepted it and awarded the bounty. My ultimate problem wsa that I was getting a 403 about the fact that directory listings were denied (the suggestion about index.php made me think about that). I had to catch the 403 exception from Guzzle and print the body of the request to know it was a "directory listing denied" error instead of a certificate error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
If you are using private key then you have to use ssl_key option it will not 
work with cert.You can use **cert** options only with client certificate.
```

This error occurs because of three reason.

1. Correct certificate path is not provided. Hence not able to read &
   pass the certificate information to server.
2. The server failed to authenticate the request because of invalid certificate.
3. Php curl is not able to read the certificate file because of file owner/permission issue.

How Guzzle set ssl curl path:

- Guzzle use CURLOPT_CAINFO for file & CURLOPT_CAPATH for multiple certificates in directory
- Default certificate path is `vendor/Http/Resources/cacert.pem`.
- If you don't use phar in require_once then you can replace existing certificate file with your new certificate because it initialize SSL on every request. This will work without changing the code.
- Guzzle uses `ssl.certificate_authority` parameter to set the curl ssl certification. It supports values as false,true or file path
- You can set the file path while class initialization as below-

  ```
  $cert_file = '/var/www/stack/25924147/cert/example.pem'; #Use absolute path as relative path will not work
  $client = new Client();
  $client->setDefaultOption('verify',true); #pass it for self-signed certificate
  $client->setSslVerification($cert_file,true,2);  #Last Verify Option states default value is 2. When the verify value is 0, the connection succeeds regardless of the names in the certificate. Use that ability with caution!. When the verify value is 1, curl_easy_setopt will return an error
  try{
      $request = $client->get($url);
      $options = $request->getCurlOptions(); #used to check curl options is set properly.
      var_dump($options); 
      $response = $client->send($request);
      echo $response . PHP_EOL;
      print 'HI' . PHP_EOL;
  }catch( Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException $e){
      print_r($e->getResponse());
      echo "\n Curl Error \n";
  }catch(Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException $e){
     print_r($e->getResponse());
     echo "\n Response Error \n";
  }catch( Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException $e){
    print_r($e->getResponse());
    echo "\n REquest Error \n";
  }
  ```

**OR** If you wants to pass certificate on every request try below code

```
   $cert_file = '/var/www/stack/25924147/cert/example.pem'; #Use absolute path as relative path will not work
   $client = new Client();
   $request = $client->get('https://www.example.com', array(), array(

      'ssl_key' => array('/etc/pki/private_key.pem')

  )


With Passoword - 
 $request = $client->get('https://www.example.com', array(), array(

     'ssl_key' => array('/etc/pki/private_key.pem', 's3cr3tp455w0rd')

 )
```

For Guzzle Http client Doc check - [The Guzzle HTTP client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/docs/http-client/client.rst)

Answer (score 2):

First, because this lead to some confusion, there are two versions of Guzzle available on Gihub:

- [Guzzle3](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3) (the old version, you are using)
- [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)  (the new, rewritten version)

Here comes two (tested working) examples one for each version of Guzzle:

**For the recent versions of [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) (not the so called older version Guzzle3)** it should be:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get($url, array('cert' => $cert_file));

var_dump($response);
```

Make sure the client certificate is stored in `PEM` format. If the certificate is protected by a password, you'll need to specify it like this:

```
$response = $client->get($url, 
    array('cert' => array($cert_file, 'password' => '****'));
```

**!!** Note the above code to provide the password is described in the manual but didn't worked in the recent version.

**For the old version Guzzle3 (you are using)**

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

// Create a client and provide a base URL
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->get($url, array(), array(
    'cert' => $cert_file
));

// You must send a request in order for the transfer to occur
$response = $request->send();

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about PEM. Does curl use a different format than guzzle for the certificate? Note that I'm running this code one-piece after the other and the exact same $cert_file value works fine for curl and not for guzzle. Nothing about $url nor $cert_file changes.

Comment: Also, your comment about ->get() sending the request is not consistent with the guzzle docs nor my experience. Can you point to a reference about that?

Comment: Take the first example on this page: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/clients.rst .. Did you tried my code? (I was to lazy to setup a client cert based authentication test server so far).

Comment: Oh, I see it is a version problem. You are using a different version of Guzzle then me. (I used the most recent)... Need to check the `3.9.2` ..

Comment: @greggles You are using the old version (and should probably upgrade.) This lead to some confusion on my site. I have given an example for both versions, the new and the old one. I basically just missed, that the options parameter for `get()` comes at the third place in the old version of Guzzle. Also the meaning of the method `get()` has changed in the new version as you can see. Hope it works for you (note the password problem in the new version, will probably create a patch.. but tomorrow ;) )

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. At this point I can't upgrade as there is other software that depends on this version of guzzle. Certainly we'll upgrade at some point but I'm looking for a solution on the old version until then.

Comment: I posted a solution for the old version. As I said I've tested them both, is it working for you?