# Guzzle Post request with auth

Tags: php, json, curl, guzzle

First time I am using guzzle. Can anybody let me know How can I write Guzzle call for this request.

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://xyz/api/v1/accounts.json -d '{"user":{"username":"test","password":"xyz","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","email":"test@test.com","roles":["Administrator"]}}'
```

I am facing problem in -u of curl request.

```
I have written this code.
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
    'auth' => ['username:password'],
    'json' => [
        'username' => 'test'
    ],
]);
$results = $response->json();
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924147/moving-curl-client-ssl-to-guzzle) but unable to call API

Any Suggestion or Help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#auth) basic auth should be specified using array of two elements (login and password):

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = "//xyz/api/v1/accounts.json";
        $response = $client->post($url, [
            'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json'],
            'auth' => [
                'test', 
                'xyz'
            ],
            'json' => [
                "username"=>"xyz",
                "password"=>"xyz",
                "first_name"=>"test",
                "last_name"=>"test",
                "email"=>"test@test.com",
                "roles"=>"Administrator"
            ], 
        ]);
```